# action for selecting an index in an indexed uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uikit

I have sectionIndexTitlesForTableView implemented in my controller class.
when I selected an index, I want to have my custom action.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are wanting is something to happen when you select an item in the table?

implement the delegate method

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: nope, there is sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, which will enabled the index on right side of the table

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can override the default behavior of the index, nor do I think doing so a good idea. It's meant as a shortcut to jump to a specific section in the table, and is used as such in every other app that uses section indexes—what custom behavior do you want, exactly?

Comment: basically in my app i am using facebook graph api to load list of friends and their pictures.  For loading pictures I am doing in a way that when user scrolls the table, it will check the visible rows.
Based on visible rows in UITableView, I will partially load each friend's display picture.
So accomplish this feature, I am using UIScrollView's delegate methods
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
But I can't do it for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView.